# How to check only alphanumeric and other language alphabet by using preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to create a SEO friendly string only from alphanumeric and characters of my native language. It is sinhala.

My expected string should be something like this:

```
$myString = "this-is-a-දහසක්-බාධක-දුක්-කම්කටොලු-මැදින්-ලෝකය-දිනන්නට-වෙර-දරන";
```

I am using a function to create the string like this. And that function is as follow:

```
function seoUrl($string) {
    //Lower case everything
    $string = strtolower($string);
    //Make alphanumeric (removes all other characters)
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-]/", "", $string);
    //Clean up multiple dashes or whitespaces
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);
    //Convert whitespaces and underscore to dash
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $string);
    return $string;
}
```

This function only works for English characters and output of above string as below:

```
$title = seoUrl("this-is-a-දහසක්-බාධක-දුක්-කම්කටොලු-මැදින්-ලෝකය-දිනන්නට-වෙර-දරන");
echo $title; // this-is-a-
```

Can anybody tell me how to modify above function to get all my characters (including my native language characters)

Hope somebody may help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `/u` flag for unicode and `\pL` for letters, `\pN` for numbers.

Edit: due to some multibyte characters, mb_ereg_replace is the good choice:

```
function seoUrl($string) {
    //Lower case everything
    $string = strtolower($string);
    //Make alphanumeric (removes all other characters)
    $string = mb_ereg_replace("[^\x0D-\x0E\w\s-]", "", $string);
    //Clean up multiple dashes or whitespaces
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);
    //Convert whitespaces and underscore to dash
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", $string);
    return $string;
}
$title = seoUrl("this-is-a-දහසක්-බාධක-දුක්-කම්කටොලු-මැදින්-ලෝකය-දිනන්නට-වෙර-දරන");
echo $title;
```

**Output:**

```
this-is-a-දහසක්-බාධක-දුක්-කම්කටොලු-මැදින්-ලෝකය-දිනන්නට-වෙර-දරන
```

Comment: But some parts are missing in sinhala characters. Please look at two string closely, you will notice the difference.

Answer (score 2):

You use multibyte encoding. preg_replace doesn't work with multibyte encoding. You should use [`mb_ereg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg-replace.php) function